# C++ Templates compilation

Tags: c++, templates, compilation

I am failing to answer questions related to templates. Basically how templates are compiled by the compiler. I googled but did not find answers. Can somebody help me

Comment: You need to be a bit more specific.

Comment: @Neil I heard that template compilation involves two steps from a interviewer, but I did not get it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Templates themselves are not compiled, particular instantiations of templates are. Templates can be instantiated by simply being used or by being explicitly instantiated

E.g. given a function template:

```
template<class T> void f() {}
```

This is just a *template* for a function, which you can use:

```
f<int>(); // compiler will instantiate a concrete f<int>()
```

... leading to that particular instantiation being compiled. Alternatively you can explicitly instantiate it:

```
template void f<int>();
```

The original template however is never compiled, it is just used to create concrete instances.

Comment: but if we do not instantiate any concrete instance, and if there are any syntax error in template compiler throws errors. Why is this

Comment: @siri Templates are not compiled, but they are parsed by the compiler before any instantiations takes place, which means they must be syntactically correct.

Answer (score 3):

Read a book, like [C++ Templates - The Complete Guide](http://www.josuttis.com/tmplbook/) by David Vandevoorde and Nicolai M. Josuttis. Beside that it explains how to use them it also does give some insight on how they are implemented.